# How do you execute a server-side Python script using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I have a very simple Python file, called python1.py, whose contents are:

```
f = open('C:\\Temp\\test.txt', 'w')
f.write('Succeeded')
f.close()
```

I wish to execute this from JavaScript, like so:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/cgi-bin/python1.py",
   success: function (msg) {
       alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
   }
});
```

However, all that happens is that I get an alert showing me the contents of the Python script. The file C:\Temp\test.txt does not get created, so clearly the Python was not executed.

How do I persuade the code to execute the Python script instead of just reading it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you able to execute the script directly from the browser. This looks more like a webserver config issue than jquery's

Comment: No, I can't execute it directly. I'm using Apache 2.2. Any ideas what setting I need to alter?

Comment: Okay, I've found the mistake: I used Alias in my httpd.conf file instead of ScriptAlias. I'm now returning the output of the Python file, but it still won't create the temp file. I will leave that to  another question

Answer (score 7):

You simply need to configure your web server to execute your *.py scripts, instead of serving them as plain text.

If you are using Apache as a web server, you need to enable [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/) or [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).

---

**EDIT:**

Since you are using using Apache, you may want to check the following article, which briefly describes how to set up the mod_python module:

- [A Brief Introduction to Apache's mod_python Module](http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/29357/1954)

Answer (score 7):

You could also use the opensource project Pico. It's a really elegant way of calling server side Python code from client side Javascript.

The author has provided some simple examples here https://github.com/fergalwalsh/pico/wiki/Example-1:-Hello-World

Comment: Is there any way PICO can be used in GAE apps?

Comment: After many headaches trying to get Apache and mod_python to work, I (luckily) stumbled across this post, where I was able to get my JS and Python talking to each other in no time flat. Pico rocks! Extremely easy to set up and implement.

Answer (score 1):

If your script is that simple, you would be best off using CGI on the server side rather than mod_python or mod_wsgi as suggested by others. For details on how to set up Apache for CGI with Python and simple script examples see:

http://webpython.codepoint.net/cgi_tutorial

Comment: why is CGI better than mod_python?