# Returning a Python response to the same page using jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

I want to use jQuery ajax and a simple web form with two fields to send values to a python script. I want the results to be displayed within a div tag on the same calling page (index.html.en).

I have a page called index.html.en, I click the submit button, the values from the form are passed to the python script (printname.py), and the results are returned and displayed within a div tag that is placed under the form on the index.html.en page. I have spent the last two days looking for answers or examples but I haven't found any. I'm not sure if what I'm attempting to do, and the way I want to do it is possible. I'm using Mac OS Lion and my web server is up and working. Currently my code validates that the fields are not empty but it doesn't return anything. Any help would be appreciated. My code and file structure is below.

File Structure:

```
Library
  WebServer
    CGI-Exectutables/printname.py
    Documents/projects/rambo/index.html.en
```

HTML File: Index.html.en

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>

function ValidateFields(){
  $("#fname_error").hide();
  $("#lname_error").hide();
  var theForm = document.forms[0];
  var isError = "false";

  for (i=0;i<theForm.length;i++){
    if(theForm.elements[i].getAttribute("type") == "text"){
      var theFormField = theForm.elements[i];
      var theFormFieldValue = theForm.elements[i].value;

      if(theFormFieldValue == ""){
        isError = "true";
        var theFormFieldName = theForm.elements[i].getAttribute("name");
        console.log(theFormFieldName);
        switch (theFormFieldName)
        {
        case "first_name":
          $("#fname_error").show();
          break;
        case "last_name":
          $("#lname_error").show();
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if(isError == "true"){
    return false;
  }
  //The reset method clears all fields on the form
  theform.reset();
}
</script>

<script>
function Initialize_Form(){
  $("#fname_error").hide();
  $("#lname_error").hide();  
}
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  Initialize_Form();

  $("#one").submit(function(){
    ValidateFields();
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  $.ajax(
  {
  type: "POST",
  url: "/cgi-bin/printname.py",
  data: "Catsup",
  success: function(response)
  {
    $("#response_1").text("We returned python returned" + response);
  }
  });
  return false;

});

</script>

<title>Mike's Test Ajax Python File</title>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test Page</h1>
  <form id="one" name="one">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>first:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="first_name"></td>
      <td><div id="fname_error"><p>first name is required</p></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>last:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="last_name"></td>
      <td><div id="lname_error"><p>Last name is required</p></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
  <div id = "response_1"></div>
  <div id = "response_2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Python File: printname.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi, cgitb

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fname = form.getvalue('first_name')
lname = form.getvalue('last_name')

print "Content-Type: text/html"
print

print (fname + ' ' + lname)
```

Again, I'm fairly new to python and ajax so I'm not sure if the way I'm trying to do this can be done.

Comment: Your Javascript is sending Ajax, but your Python script is expecting CGI.  Look at this link, and make sure your server is configured to allow execution of Python scripts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201561/how-do-you-execute-a-server-side-python-script-using-jquery

Comment: Yes my server is configured to allow execution of Python scripts. The link provided did not help with my question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start using the development tools of your browser so you can debug your javascript code (step through it line by line, set break-points etc.).

In this case it looks like your `$.ajax(..)` call is not part of your `$('#one').submit(...)` handler, which means it doesn't get called when you submit your form. You can verify that this is the problem by `print("hello world")` in your cgi script (it should show up immediately on document ready).

The `data:` parameter in you `$.ajax(..)` call should be something like `$('form#one').serialize()`, so that actual parameters (with values) are sent to python.  (I'm going from memory here, look it up in the jQuery docs).

There are many frameworks that handle all the minutia of processing requests/responses that you might want to look into also.  cgi is very 90's ;-)