# Simple way of executing python script server side

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have searched alot but nothing I found has helped me. Basically all I want is make my python script run server side. Is there a simple way to accomplish this by using only html and javascript/jQuery and Ajax?  Or maybe if I install a python module into apache and include the script on the html the script will run? All the script does Is create a file and I dont want to use any libraries.

Comment: Have a look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) microframework.

Comment: Can you check the following SO post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201561/how-do-you-execute-a-server-side-python-script-using-jquery